# Regex: delete between brackets, but only if below character length

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, python-re

I have strings such as:

```
this is a text ( with parts in brackets ) . This is another string ( with a very long string between brackets that should not be removed because it is too long being over 100 characters )
```

Desired output:

```
this is a text  . This is another string ( with a very long string between brackets that should not be removed because it is too long being over 100 characters )
```

I can match the bracket content with (with the goal to replace it with an empty string to remove it).

```
\s\(.+\)\s
```

Now, if there is no closing bracket, the regex deletes to much text. I would like to delete content between two brackets, but only if the length is < 100 chars. How an I do this with regex? I understand I would need a lookahead expression? I appreciate the help!

Edit: Using the following expression, as suggested doesn't work as solution:

```
\s\(.+\){1,100}\s
```

Comment: `{0,99}` quantifier = 0 to 99 occurrences

Comment: Hi Wiktor, I have tried it however it doesn't work unfortunately. Thanks for your help anyhow!

Comment: The expression you used `\s\(.+\){1,100}\s` counts between 1 and 100 right brackets. What you need is `\s\(.{0,100}\)\s`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
\s\([^()]{0,100}\)\s
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/gCUZh6/2). Set the limiting quantifier after the `[^()]` pattern, it matches any character other than parens.

Example code:

```
import re

test_str = "this is a text ( with parts in brackets ) . This is another string ( with a very long string between brackets that should not be removed because it is too long being over 100 characters )"

print( re.sub(r"\s\([^()]{0,100}\)\s", "", test_str) )
```

Output:

```
this is a text. This is another string ( with a very long string between brackets that should not be removed because it is too long being over 100 characters )
```